# how to show and scroll automatically a hidden div at bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

On a click on the image I have to show a hidden div with effects such as scroll down automatically to the bottom

my code looks like:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#test').click(function() {
        $('.contact-form').toggle("100");

      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="contact" status="closed">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="contact-nav"></div>
        <div class="contact-form-trigger open" id="test">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/dugh1.png')?>" class="doug img-resfponsive hidden-xs" alt="Doug the man!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="color-div"></div>
  <div class="contact-form " style="display: none;">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="address">
            <div class="address-div">
              <h3>Address</h3>
              <h5><?php echo $company[1]->content; ?>
                            </h5>
              <h5>Phone: <?php echo $company[2]->content; ?></h5>
              <a href="#">
                <?php echo $company[3]->content; ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons">
              <h4>follow us</h4>
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a class="social-icon" href="<?php echo $company[7]->content; ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="social-icon" href="<?php echo $company[8]->content; ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="social-icon" href="<?php echo $company[9]->content; ?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="social-icon" href="<?php echo $company[10]->content; ?>"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

By using this script i can show the hidden div but it not scrolling down automatically.Now my need is to make it possible scroll down automatically when clicked on the image **dugh1.png** to show hidden div. what should I have to done for making that possible. I am very new to java script. Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try doing something like this mate

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#test').click(function() {
        $('.contact-form').toggle("100");
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $('footer').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
      });
    });
```

or check this just customize it to your needs.

Comment: Thank u very much. I am looking for the same :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

you can use this snippet

Comment: var mydiv = $("#scroll");
mydiv.scrollTop(mydiv.prop("scrollHeight"));

Comment: The above is using jquery  and works from jquery 1.6 onwards.

Comment: why dont u edit your answer instead of commenting it??